# How to make my platform side scroll

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a platform game in Flash using ActionScript 3.0, and I'm having a lot of issues with finding tutorials online to help to achieve my goal.

The idea of the game is the player will be able to jump over oncoming obstacles, and I want the platform to be moving so all the user has to do is jump.

The game looks like it has 1 platform/ground across the bottom, the player is then stood on it and all I want for now is to make the user move into the center then have the platform move instead of the player.

I can't find tutorials or code anywhere for this so can someone help by giving me some code which would point me in the direction, or a good tutorial which helps?

Comment: This won't be EXACTLY what you're after, but it's a good introduction to some basic concepts. If you can absorb a good deal of these tutorials you should have no problem solving the problems you're facing yourself... http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/as3-avoider-game-tutorial-base/

Comment: The thing is, that this site is not for this, and the game looks really simple, you should not waste your time with tutorials, but start actually learn how to program. With tutorials, you are only wasting your time because they are only showing you how to do specific things, and often by people who don't really know how to program properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what exactly do you mean by this question. If you want to make a side scroller, aÏ recommend using Vcam. If you want to create just a moving platfrom however, you can change its position using

```
instance_here.y += 10;
```

this will move the platform 10 pixels down from where its been (thanks to the +). you can change the "y" for "x" and add "-" in front of the "10". You can use Timer to move it at all times, not only once.

Comment: If you don't know what he means, why you provide an "answer"? :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov: if it's incorrect, downvote it. If not, then I'd say it's fine.

Comment: Note that it's best to try and make sure you understand what the OP is asking for, or cover all possibilities when answering if it's just a little thing and you can't comment on the question.

Comment: @OneKitten: It's better to flag it in order to be removed instead of downvote it and leave it here :)